# multiple users and multiple success url in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Hello I have 3 types of users with diffrent jsp pages. I'm a beginner with spring boot, i don't know how to make authentication with diffrent users and diffrent success url pages 
this is my application structure :

[image]

```
     package bootsample;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import bootsample.service.CustomUserDetailsService;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = CustomUserDetailsService.class)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired 
 private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

 @Autowired
 public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {    
     auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
 } 



 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {



   http.authorizeRequests()

   .antMatchers("/supervisor/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_Supervisor")

   .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
   .anyRequest().permitAll()
   .and()
     .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
     .defaultSuccessUrl("/supervisor/hello")
     .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/hello")
     .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
   .and()
     .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
   .and()
    .csrf().disable();
 }

 @Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder(){
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I tried with this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second defaultSuccessUrl is overwriting the first. Instead of defaultSuccessUrl, you probably want to use an AuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
       .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

                response.sendRedirect(...);
            }
        })
```

from the javadoc:

> Implementations can do whatever they want but typical behaviour would be to control the
>     navigation to the subsequent destination (using a redirect or a forward). For example,
>     after a user has logged in by submitting a login form, the application needs to decide
>     where they should be redirected to afterwards